How can I replace only certain values in a map of maps, while keeping all the others?
I have a very deep map of maps with lots of values, where I want to update only a few values, while keeping all the rest. I thought that maps:merge/2 would be just the ticket, but the problem with that is that it will replace every key, all the way up to the root. I only want to update the value in the leaf. This is what maps:merge/2 does:
>maps:merge(#{a => apple, b => #{c => cherry, d => date}}, #{b => #{c => cantaloupe}}).
#{a => apple, b => #{c => cantaloupe}}).

The result I would like is #{a => apple, b => #{c => cantaloupe, d => date}}. I tried working with maps:merge_with/3, but couldn't figure it out. Is there a clever way to do this?

What should happen for #{a=>apple} and #{a=>#{b =>banana}}?

Hmm, both maps would have the same structure, except that I want to get away with specifying as little as possible of it in the second map, if that makes sense? So the structure would never be different in the second map, but a sparse subset of the first one.

Using maps:merge_with/3 with a recursive function should be enough here.
A quick and dirty one-liner:
1> Fun = fun F(_K, L, R) when is_map(L) -> maps:merge_with(F, L, R); F(_K, _L, R) -> R end.
#Fun<erl_eval.17.39164016>
2> Fun(nil, #{a => apple, b => #{c => cherry, d => date}}, #{b => #{c => cantaloupe}}).
#{b => #{c => cantaloupe,d => date},a => apple}

A more readable version:
deep_merge(Left, Right) -> maps:merge_with(fun
    (_, L, R) when is_map(L) -> deep_merge(L, R); 
    (_, _, R) -> R end
, Left, Right).


There is a library for operating on nested structures such as this one: https://github.com/Shaienn/nested_maps
nested_maps:update/4 addresses this exact usecase. I would be interested in simpler solutions though.
